# WebDriver: Check that Ajax call returns no items for populating a drop down list

Tags: ajax, selenium

How to check that Ajax call **returns no items** for populating a drop down list with WebDriver? 
I've tried different timeout and waiting options for elements. Nothing works.

From the user perspective, he enters some value in the text field, waits for ajax call return and then empty dropdown list appears and suddenly disappears. 
So suppose I have autosuggest input field (like google search)  and I need to be sure that there were no auto suggestions for the selected input.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the markup, but there is usually a container (probably a `<div>` element) for showing the ajax results, it is probably hidden (ie using  `display: none;`) and becomes visible after databinding occurs. If i were you, i would locate that element and use it in WebDriverWait, perhaps using [ExpecedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29)